# Calculating total filesize in SWFUpload Queue

Tags: javascript, flash, swfupload

Is there anyway I can get the total size of all files queued from swfupload right after the user selected the files? I need to be able to display something like "0 of 184MB" when the upload is about to start.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe, answer is somewhere in the docs ? http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/#fileobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up only showing progress per file basis (1 / 10 files uploaded, etc...)